# How can I reinitialize Apache on my Mac running OS 10.6.4

Tags: macos, apache, reset

I got in a bit over my head and probably entered some wrong commands into terminal. Now I can't get my local webpages to work display. I'd like to start from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the config file and delete it.  As for the location, you can Google it.